# Western Digital My Book not recognized by WD software

Tags: external-hard-drive, raid, raid-0

A few years ago I bought a WD My Book Pro 2. It worked fine for a while, then one of the drives failed and I sent it back to be replaced under warranty. I never got around to setting up the new one when I got it back.

I finally ran out of room on my internal drive, so I tried to use the external - no go. Both drives spin up, but aren't recognized by either Disk Utility (Mac) or the WD Drive Manager. I tried on a PC as well with fresh software. Then I pulled the drives out of the enclosure (warranty is already expired) and plugged them straight into the PC. Both recognized and working 100% in RAID0. BIOS recognizes either disk as functional; Windows only sees them when both are connected due to the RAID which I can't change without the WD software.

The drives that were returned to me are the "Green" drives which I've read are NOT recommended for RAID. Is it possible that this is interfering with them reading externally? Any other ideas? My main computer is a laptop so using them internally isn't an option :(

Answer (score 0):

You can change the raid, use Windows Disk management to delete the partitions and format as basic drives, do this when they are connected straight to the PC.

Green drives will work for raid, not a problem in an enclosure.

With the drives in the enclosure and connected to a windows PC, look in disk management, they may need to be formatted.

.